# How to make a HTTP PUT request using LWP?

Tags: perl, http, perl-module, lwp-useragent

I'm trying to change this request to a HTTP PUT request, any idea how ?

```
my $request = LWP::UserAgent->new; 
my $response = 
        $request->get($url, "apikey", $apiKey, "requestDate", $requestDate);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use HTTP::Request:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $req = HTTP::Request->new("PUT", $url); 

my $res = $ua->request($req);
```

Answer (score 4):

As of 6.04, `LWP::UserAgent` has a `put` helper, so you can now do:

```
$ua->put( $url )
```

Answer (score 2):

PUT is HTTP::Request::Common.  You can build the request first and pass it into user agent.

```
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use LWP;

$agent    = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$request  = HTTP::Request::Common::PUT($url, "apikey", $apiKey, "requestDate", $requestDate); 
$response = $agent->request($request);
```