# How can I make a HTTP PUT request in perl that contains application/x-www-form-urlencoded data?

Tags: perl, http, rest

How can I make a HTTP PUT request in Perl that contains `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data?

This is an equivalent POST request that works:

```
my $ua       = new LWP::UserAgent;
my $response = $ua->post(
    $url,
    {
        "parameter1" => $value1,
        "parameter2" => $value2
    }
);
```

How would this be done as a PUT request?
There is no `put` method in LWP and the [`PUT` function in `HTTP::Request::Common`](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Request::Common#PUT-url) does not take form data.

For a discussion if a PUT request with form data is allowed, see [Can HTTP PUT request have application/x-www-form-urlencoded as the Content-Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306185/can-http-put-request-have-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-as-the-content-type)

This is an example of a PUT request, but it does not contain code to enclose form data: [How to make a HTTP PUT request using LWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463187/how-to-make-a-http-put-request-using-lwp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make `POST`-request and change its method to `PUT`:

```
use HTTP::Request::Common;

my $req = POST('http://example.com/', Content => [param => 'value']);

$req->method('PUT');

say($req->as_string);
```